# Book suggestion for discrete mathematics and algebraic structures

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm taking a course in Discrete Mathematics. I would like to have another book other than the one my professor requires (it doesn't explain stuff very well and it does have any exercises on it, it's mostly made of his notes in pdf form).

I've looked around and I've found various books covering part of the course (sets, relatios, vectors and matrices), but I can't find a lot on algebraic structures.

Could you suggest books about monoids, rings, lattices, vector spaces, groups, omomorphism and congruences? Possibly relating to discrete maths too, with exercises and solutions. I'm just a computer science  first year student, so I don't need the absolute deepest knowledge for now, but I would like to understand the subject better.

Comment: Help from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Scheinerman, E.R. Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction, 3rd ed., Brooks Cole (2012)
ISBN: 978-0840049421

That is the book that is used at Johns Hopkins University for discrete mathematics. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pinter's [A Book of Abstract Algebra](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZAo_AwAAQBAJ&dq=a%20book%20of%20abstract%20algebra&source=gbs_navlinks_s) offers a nice and gentle introduction to typical first-semester abstract algebra without skimping on rigor. Fair warning: most of the content is in the exercises (although I'm sure that solutions are available online with a bit of creative googling). Other good options include [Judson](http://abstract.ups.edu/) and [Goodman](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/algebrabook.html), both of which are open-source.

None of these options are specifically geared towards computer science students, I'm afraid, but all are very readable and broad enough to hopefully have most of what you are looking for.